# Geometry settings for default document layout?

Tags: margins, geometry

How can I obtain the corresponding settings for the `geometry` package so that the document looks just like the standard `article` or `report`?

Assume that I have a document in the default style, and I would like to modify only *some* of the layout options; for example, I might want to change the `headheight` and leave everything else the same.

Try for example the following two option settings for `geometry`, the first of which shows the default layout, and then how everything changes even if I *just* wanted to change one of the settings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
%\usepackage[showframe,headheight=1.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

There is a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2618/storing-the-original-documentclass-page-layout-with-geometry) (from which I learned about the `pass` option), but note that the following

```
\usepackage[showframe,pass,headheight=1.5cm]{geometry}
```

doesn’t work.

Comment: I thought that this can be done with the option `reset`, but it seems to be nonfunctional - perhaps a bug?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can compile your document with `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`, which will write in the `.log` file a transcript; here's the result (with A4 paper):

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* pass: disregarded the geometry package!
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=345.0pt
* \textheight=598.0pt
* \oddsidemargin=53.0pt
* \evensidemargin=54.0pt
* \topmargin=17.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=57.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
```

Since we are in a `oneside` context, all that should be needed is

```
\geometry{a4paper,textwidth=345pt,textheight=598pt}
```

But you can always check against the old transcript.

Comment: How about `a4` and `twoside`? I tried `pass` and the document seemed unchanged, when loading `geometry`usually would. I also checked my log (for `oneside` also) and was surprised to find `textwidth=345pt`, `textheight=550pt` - what is going on here ? Apparently `\documentclass[a4,twoside]{report}` produces another page size, than `\geometry{ a4paper }` !? I feel like `geometry`-paper is  too high ? Checking the log, `geometry` is narrower and higher compared to default: `\paperwidth=597.50787pt`, `\paperheight=845.04684pt` vs `\paperwidth=614.295pt`, `\paperheight=794.96999pt`

Comment: @gr4nt3d The option `a4` doesn't exist, so you get the same as for `letterpaper`. You need `\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}`

Comment: You are absolutely right, I am getting the same page size now! I must have had that error for quite a while, I guess. However, the text still wanders around a bit when using `\geometry{ ... }` (looks like it is higher) ? edit: `\topmargin=17.0pt` is default, whereas `\topmargin=-10.45126pt` for `geometry` ??

Comment: Ok, sry for spam, but I can not edit anymore: It seems like this is easily fixed by `\setlength{\topmargin}{17pt}` after `\geometry{ ... }`. I have no idea what caused it, though.

Comment: @gr4nt3d You shouldn't do `\setlength{\topmargin}{whatever}` when using `geometry`. Why would you?

Comment: As said before, the text moves because geometry somehow makes `\topmargin` go crazy to `-10`.

Comment: @gr4nt3d That's not crazy at all. It is what results from geometry calculations. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I just want my text to look the same as without geometry.

Comment: @gr4nt3d Then don't use `geometry`

Comment: How else would I do small adjustments then ? Especially I need the binding correction.