# Package geometry changes the layout also without options

Tags: geometry

This [Load the geometry package without having it change the document margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570250/13745) has no answers.
I must ask the same.

I was trying to change the margins just a bit, but when I load `\usepackage{geometry}` it changes the page layout *a lot* even without any options. I don't understand why but it seems (reading online) that it is intended behaviour: quite strange though, isn't it?

How to specify just a small adjustment, without `geometry` thinking of doing big things without being asked?

Comment: See this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23048/36296 on how to get the geometry settings which correspond to the normal layout of your class

Comment: The `[pass]` option is what you seek.

Comment: I think that the default layout was done according to the American taste of  certain time, but actually many people, maybe also in America, want narrower margins to save trees, to save screen space, or funnily, even because this is the   "gold standard"  learned in Word.  In this cases, no matter why, is great to change to the still generous  1.25in margins and gain 85pt of text width  just loading the package.