# How to change margins in ieeetrans.cls document? Note: geometry package conflicts with ieeetrans.cls format.

Tags: margins, geometry, ieeetran

I'm writing a conference paper that must be in/adhere to the ieeetrans.cls format.

For a landscaped table I need to make the left and right margins smaller, but just the `\usepackage{geometry}` command changes the whole paper setup! It's conflicting with the ieeetrans.cls file evidently. On the other hand, if I use the geometry package, I can indeed make the table look good at the expense of every other page.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I do not see why you need to change page layout for landscape table. If it is set as `sidewaystable`, then table will appear on middle of text block.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is covered in [Storing the original document class page layout with `geometry`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2618/5764).

Comment: There is a class `IEEEtran`. The class file `IEEEtran.cls` contains a **warning**: "Authors should not alter font sizes, baselineskip ('leading'), margins or other spacing values in an attempt to squeeze more material on one page. The IEEE's  own typesetting software will restore the correct vlaues when re-typesetting/proofing the submitted document, possibly resulting in unexpected article over length charges."

Comment: You are not allowed to alter the class file if it is going to be published in IEEE.

Comment: Zarko, i tried that first and it didn't work- the table wouldn't render, likely because it was hanging over the right margin? The other method worked. 

Werner, yes! that's the answer. Feel free to post as the answer if you like. 

Percusse- not sure they'll care for a landscaped table page but we shall see.

Comment: @travelingbones, than you need to tweak or redesign a table, not change a page layout. Provide please a  minimal working example with your table, maybe than someone here can help you.

Comment: Percusse, not changing the class file. Zarko, thanks. The table fits, but overruns the margins. the maneuver of setting the margins just centers it. I'll see how it builds when i submit the paper.

Comment: @travelingbones Maybe I'm going crazy here, but if you want to have a page with only the table in it, in landscape and without changing the format, why not create a blank new page and put the table on the background? Not elegant, I know, but not matter how IEEE compile they'd get the same result as you.

Comment: Santos, thanks for the suggestion. Can you advise on how to do this? I will say that I"m under a deadline, and the huge table now looks beautiful, so I'm interested in your suggestion but also moving on.

Comment: There is the ugly but legal option of using \noindent\resizebox{\linewidth}{\textheight}{...} from graphicx.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the following format

```
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTtoptextmargin}{2cm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTbottomtextmargin}{2cm}

\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,draftcls]{IEEEtran} 
...
```

credit: https://andrejserafim.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/ieeetran-page-margins/